# Update filename of the extracted file in front of the records in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a requirement on which I am getting no idea how to start with and request your assistance.

I have a SQL table which gets loaded via a Stored Procedure in SSIS. Once the table is loaded there are some checks which gets applied on the table and then it proceeds ahead with the file extraction.
The records from the table now flows into a single CSV file.
There is a condition that the file can have only 100K records, hence I split the files and a suffix gets added to the file name. For example, if XYZ is the file name, then based on records count the file splits into XYZ_1.csv, XYZ_2.csv, XYZ_3.csv.

The task is I need to update the filename in front of the records in the table, which means if file XYZ_1.csv has rows from ID 1 to 100 then I must get the filename in front of those records as XYZ_1.csv and so on for the next.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Thanks.

Comment: "must get the filename in front of those records as XYZ_1.csv" -- do you mean your CSV file then would have `XYZ_1.csv` at the start of each line? Post the code you have now.

Comment: The process that splits the file is in the best position to record that information. So how is that accomplished? If your process is based on the use of some standard file splitting application after export, your goal may be impossible without significant changes.